# ms access data macro access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm using Microsoft Office 2010, I'd like to use Data Macro of MS Access but all the icons on the ribbon (before change, before delete, after insert, etc ) are not available. Do I have to install something else ?

Comment: What does 'not available' mean - are they displayed but greyed out? They only show on the Table tab when a table is open.

Comment: Is the database file an .mdb file? If so, you'll need to convert it to an .accdb file before you can use data macros.

Comment: Yes, it was a .mdb , that was the problem, thank you very much